# How should i query SQL from web application correctly?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am making a web application and would like to know the best way to populate a listbox with values from a sql query, then populate textboxes when one of the values in the listbox is selected.  It seems awful slow.  Currently, I open a connection (from an xml file) and query, putting the SSN's into the listbox.  Then, on selectedindexchanged, re-open and query again (same query) to get the names associated with that SSN and put those results into the textbox.  Is there a better (faster) way to do this?  Here's the code for what i have currently:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private SqlConnection Sqlconnection;//= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxxConnectionString"].ToString());
        private SqlCommand command;
        private string sqlQuery = "";
        private SqlDataReader reader;
        private static string configFile=@"C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Config.xml";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get connection info from config.xml
        /// </summary>
        private void ReadConnection()
        {
            string conn = String.Empty;

            //Create xml document
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            //Load the config file (hard-coded for now)
            xmlDoc.Load(configFile);
            XmlNodeList connection = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Connection");
            conn = connection[0].InnerText;
            Sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(conn);
            //return conn;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get query from config.xml
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string ReadQuery()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlQuery))
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(configFile);
                XmlNodeList query = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Query");
                sqlQuery = query[0].InnerText;
            }

            return sqlQuery;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Populates textboxes on listBox index changed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ReadConnection();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP (100) S.PlanID, S.EmployerID, S.VendorID, S.SSN, D.First, D.Middle, D.Last, D.State, S.NumLoans, S.TypeAcct, S.ERBalance, S.YTDEEContrib FROM SparkData AS S WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN Demographics AS D WITH(NOLOCK) ON S.SSN = D.SSN ORDER BY S.SSN", Sqlconnection);
                command = new SqlCommand(ReadQuery(), Sqlconnection);
                Sqlconnection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            //Assign to textbox here
                            if (reader["SSN"].ToString() == ListBox2.SelectedValue)
                            {
                                TextBox1.Text = reader["First"].ToString();
                                TextBox2.Text = reader["Middle"].ToString();
                                TextBox3.Text = reader["Last"].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Sqlconnection.Close();
                SqlConnection.ClearPool(Sqlconnection);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Connect to sql and populate listbox
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ReadConnection();
                command = new SqlCommand(ReadQuery(), Sqlconnection);
                Sqlconnection.Open();
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //Assign SSNs to listbox
                        ListBox2.Items.Add(reader["SSN"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Sqlconnection.Close();
                SqlConnection.ClearPool(Sqlconnection);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
    <%@ Page Title="xxx Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about xxx, Inc. <a href="http://www.tsacg.com/" title="xxx Website">www.xxx.com</a>
        <br />
        Here is the <a href="https://xxx-sql38.xxx.com/"
            title="xxx, Inc Intranet Portal">xxx Intranet Portal</a>.
    </p>
    <div align="center">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Connect" 
            ToolTip="Click to populate the SSN ListBox"/>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="true"
        onselectedindexchanged="ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="200px">
    </asp:ListBox>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="125" runat="server">First Name</asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" Width="25" runat="server">MI</asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" Width="125" runat="server">Last Name</asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <%--<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxxDataConnectionString %>"--%>


    <%--SelectCommand="SELECT TOP (100) S.PlanID, S.EmployerID, S.VendorID, S.SSN, D.First, D.Middle, D.Last, D.State, S.NumLoans, S.TypeAcct, S.ERBalance, S.YTDEEContrib FROM SparkData AS S WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN Demographics AS D WITH (NOLOCK) ON S.SSN = D.SSN ORDER BY S.SSN">
</asp:SqlDataSource>--%>
    <%--<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
            DataTextField="SSN" DataValueField="SSN" Width="200px" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true"
        onSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>--%>
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the total data size, you can cache all the possible combinations on the client side so that when they change the select value you can update the textbox. If all possible combinations are, say, less than 300KB then it might be reasonable to send this to the client browser depending on the speed of the connection.

Doing a round-trip to the server to populate the textbox, if the expectation is that it will be instant feedback, is always going to be slower than you like. Of course, it could also be that your DB queries are slow for some reason, so investigate that as well.

Other considerations:

- If this is for an internal app where the clients and the server are on the same LAN, then connection speed will hopefully be even faster, so it might be reasonable, depending on your use case, to cache even larger amounts of data (several MB?)
- If this is for an app that has slow or inconsistent connections, again depending on your needs and the capabilities of the client browsers, it might be best to limit the amount of data to you try send to the client. If I understand where you're coming from, it sounds like a tradeoff between initial page load time and responsiveness of the page once it's loaded (and cached data, if any, is available on the client machine).

Comment: How do i cache all combinations on the client side?  Do you have some code or an example?

Comment: Its taking like 4 or 5 seconds each time i select a different item in the listbox.  I made a desktop app to do this before, and i put the entire dataSet into the listbox, then just showed the SSN.  This allows me to already still have the data for the names.  Could I and how do I do this in web application?

Comment: It's not a quick thing to do, necessarily, but here's some reading material that covers the topic from multiple angles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404101.aspx - also might search around for **"caching data client side javascript"** for other resources

Answer (score 0):

a few comments regarding your code-

1. opening and closing connections for each request is very inefficient. I would guess that the lag you're experiencing isn't because of the SQL query, but because of the overhead of opening a connection to the DB.
   You may want to take a look at connection management / pooling solutions ([small example](http://betav.com/blog/billva/2007/05/managing_and_monitoring_net_co.html); google surely has plenty more).
2. after initializing your command query (`SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP (100) S.PlanID, S.EmployerID, S.VendorID, S.SSN, D.First, D.Middle, D.Last, D.State, S.NumLoans, S.TypeAcct, S.ERBalance, S.YTDEEContrib FROM SparkData AS S WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN Demographics AS D WITH(NOLOCK) ON S.SSN = D.SSN ORDER BY S.SSN", Sqlconnection);`) you immediately overrun it with `command = new SqlCommand...`. why is that?
3. continuing my first remark- writing queries as strings in your code is both inefficient and insecure. If you have the time, i'd read a little about [OR/M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)s (my favorite is nhibernate)
4. also i'd look at [n-tiered architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-tier) (depending on how big your app is); I really don't like data-access in presentation layer :)

If you have any more specific questions feel free to post them here.
If you're looking for comments and ways to improve your existing code, stack exchange now has a [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions).
best of luck.

Comment: 2.  Thanks, i got rid of the line where i made the query the first time.

Comment: Ok I read the article and it makes some sense.  Can you show me how to actually implement this in my example?  Thanks!